# jquery "see more" text plugin that retains html

Tags: jquery-plugins, tinymce, string-formatting

I use this jquery plugin for "see more" text:

http://keith-wood.name/moreRef.html

I save from tinymce editor html text into mysql database. Then I display html text in a php page, and I use "see more" text jquery plugin for show only 100 words of text.

My problem is that that plugin doesn't retain html formatted text, but it changes html formatted text into simple text, it remove html tag.

How can I retain text with html tag for display formatting text properly and have also "see more" link?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure css and keep the html in place. Here is a JS fiddle (less and more will not be displayed on IE6,7,8 and the content will be expanded)

http://jsfiddle.net/6sj4e/45/

```
.text {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%\9;
  }

input.less-more,
input.less-more:checked ~ label.more,
input.less-more:not(:checked) ~ label.less {
    display: none;
}
```

and the html :

```
<input id="chbox" class="less-more" type="checkbox">
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
<label for="chbox" class='more'>more</label>
<label for="chbox" class='less'>less</label>
```